# How can i open terminal through a php command in ubuntu?

Tags: php, terminal, exec, ubuntu-12.04, shell-exec

I have tried exec, shell_exec, system but they didn't work for me.

```
<?php
shell_exec('gnome-terminal');
?>
```

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You need to sit at the machine to make use of that terminal, and if you do, you can just open it directly.

Comment: I got no error message @DanielS.

Comment: Basically i want to execute a command './toolkits/collaborative_filtering/svdpp --training=/home/zubair/graphchi_v0.2.6/graphchi/smallnetflix_mm.train.txt --validation=/home/zubair/graphchi_v0.2.6/graphchi/smallnetflix_mm.validate.txt --binary_relevance_thresh=4 --sgd_gamma=1e-6 --max_iter=30 --quiet=1 --sgd_step_dec=0.9999 --sgd_lambda=1e-6 --D=3 --minival=1 --maxval=10' through php directly but it is not working so i think to open a terminal from php and than paste that command on that terminal....  May it works for me @Thilo

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to run binary file through php .... if it is Try this... Also make sure the binary file has 0777 permission

```
<?php 

//Command 
$cmd = './svdpp --training=/home/zubair/graphchi_v0.2.6/graphchi/smallnetflix_mm.train.txt --validation=/home/zubair/graphchi_v0.2.6/graphchi/smallnetflix_mm.validate.txt --binary_relevance_thresh=4 --sgd_gamma=1e-6 --max_iter=30 --quiet=1 --sgd_step_dec=0.9999 --sgd_lambda=1e-6 --D=3 --minival=1 --maxval=10';


//Binary Directory Path
$cwd = '/toolkits/collaborative_filtering/';

$descriptorspec = array (
        0 => array (
                "pipe",
                "r" 
        ),
        1 => array (
                "pipe",
                "w" 
        ),
        2 => array (
                "pipe",
                "r" 
        ) 
);

$process = proc_open ( $cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd );

if (is_resource ( $process )) {
    fclose ( $pipes [0] );

    echo 'Progress Output >> ' . stream_get_contents ( $pipes [1] );
    fclose ( $pipes [1] );

    echo 'Error >> ' . stream_get_contents ( $pipes [2] );
    fclose ( $pipes [2] );

    echo 'Proce_close >> '.proc_close ( $process );
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks dear Rajesh R i have executed it and it gave me an error... "Progress Output >> Error >> Proce_close >> 127"

Comment: 127 is becuase file not found (/toolkits/collaborative_filtering/svdpp )